# New-Object add-member - cannot add a member - powershell

Tags: powershell, psobject

I have a problem :(
I have many errors when I add New object with the same name of property which previously Object .

> "Add-Member : Cannot add a member with the name "ServerName" because a
>   member with that name already exists. To overwrite the member anyway,
>   add the Force par ameter to your command."

it works but with errors;) 
Have someone a solution for me ??

Below example code :

```
$OutputObj = @()

$OutputObj += New-Object -TypeName PSobject
$OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ServerName -Value "server1"
$OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Status -Value "online"
$OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Uptime -Value "01:20"

$OutputObj += New-Object -TypeName PSobject
$OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ServerName -Value "server2"
$OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Status -Value "online"
$OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Uptime -Value "01340"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are adding the member on the array, not on the object. Try the following:

```
$OutputObj = @()

$NewObj = New-Object -TypeName PSobject
$NewObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ServerName -Value "server1"
$NewObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Status -Value "online"
$NewObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Uptime -Value "01:20"

$OutputObj += $NewObj

$NewObj = New-Object -TypeName PSobject
$NewObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ServerName -Value "server2"
$NewObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Status -Value "online"
$NewObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Uptime -Value "01340"
$OutputObj += $NewObj
```

Alernatively, I would do the following:

```
$OutputObj = @()
$OutputObj += New-Object -TypeName PSobject -Property @{
    ServerName = "server1"
    Status = "Online"
    Uptime = "01:20"
}


$OutputObj += New-Object -TypeName PSobject -Property @{
    ServerName = "server2"
    Status = "Online"
    Uptime = "01340"
}
```

Since Add-Member destroys and generates a new object each time it is used.

Comment: But i need all in one object

Comment: In your solution output of $OutpuObj is only the last member - server2, I need server1 and server2 in output